# How to split element in an ArrayList in multidimensional arrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have the following:

```
[[Statistics (pH)], [ Upright Normal Recumbent Normal Total]]
```

I want to split the first element of the second element on whitespace so that I end up with:

```
[[Statistics (pH)], [Upright,Normal,Recumbent,Normal,Total]]
```

My code so far:

```
for (ArrayList<List<String>> row2 : StatspH) {
row2.get(1).get(0).split("\\s");
}
```

but nothing happens

Comment: Java strings are immutable. `row2.get(1).get(0).split("\\s")` splits the string, but you are discarding the returned `String[]`.

Comment: String methods are not mutators, in fact String itself in Java is immutable. `split()` will return a new instance of String[].

Comment: Also, you'd need to trim before splitting to get that result.

Comment: Ok so how to replace the whole element with the new array from split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Strings [are immutable](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/04/why-string-is-immutable-in-java/), so you need to store the return value of `split("\\s")` in the correct `List`.

I recommend something like

```
for (ArrayList<List<String>> row2 : StatspH) {
    List<String> stats = row2.get(1);

    // remove() returns the object that was removed
    String allStats = stats.remove(0);

    Collections.addAll(stats, allStats.split("\\s"));
}
```

Note that we're removing the original string first, then adding all of the 'split' values.